# web crawler/spider to fetch ajax based link

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-crawler

I want to create a web crawler/spider to iteratively fetch all the links in the webpage including javascript-based links (ajax), catalog all of the Objects on the page, build and maintain a site hierarchy. My question is:

- Which language/technology should be better (to fetch javascript-based links)?
- Is there any open source tools there?

Thanks

Brajesh

Answer (score 0):

You can automate the browser. For example, have a look at http://watir.com/

Answer (score 0):

Fetching ajax links is something that even the search-giants haven't accomplished yet. It is because, the ajax links are dynamic and the command and response both vary greatly as per the user's actions. That's probably why, SEF-AJAX (Search Engine Friendly AJAX) is now being developed. It is a technique that makes a website completely indexable to search engines that when visited by a web browser, acts as a web application. For reference, you may check this link: http://nixova.com

No offence but I dont see any way of tracking ajax links. That's where my knowledge ends. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with php, simple_html_dom and java. let the php crawler copy the pages on your local machine or webserver, open it with an java application (jpane or something) mark all text as focused and grab it. send it to your database or where you want to store it. track all a tags or tags with an onclick or mouseover attribute. check what happens when you call it again. if the source html (the document returned from server) size or md5 hash is different you know its an effective link and can grab it. i hope you can understand my bad english :D